# Calculating md5Hash or crc32 in PHP for Google Cloud Storage object

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I am having trouble calculating a file hash for Google Cloud Storage objects as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hashes-etags).

I've tried `crc32($filepath)`, `hash_file('crc32b', $filepath)`, and the md5 equivalents, but nothing matches what they come up with. I've also tried base64 encoding the result but I was just guessing at that point.

How do I get the hashes below in PHP based on this file? https://storage.googleapis.com/hashing-test/0067142-0.png

crc32c: `wPjVCQ==`

md5Hash: `SNsMU2l0FHH+BE3Fg79Vew==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the Google library source code. The following returns a string identical to the one created in the object info.

```
use Google\CRC32\CRC32;

function getCrc32($content) {
  $crc32c = CRC32::create(CRC32::CASTAGNOLI);
  $crc32c->update($content);
  return base64_encode($crc32c->hash(true));
}

$hash = getCrc32(file_get_contents('/path/to/foo.png'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same but for python using crcmod:

```
import crcmod    
with open("smallfile.txt", "rb") as f:
tmp = b''.join(f.readlines())
crc32_func = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x11EDC6F41, initCrc=0, xorOut=0xFFFFFFFF)
crc32c = hex(crc32_func(tmp))
print (crc32c)
```